# Specify that a spawned process returns to a parent

Tags: flowchart

I am using yED to build an application flow-chart, and I can't figure out a 'nice' looking way of representing that a GUI's call to spawn a process loops back to the GUI process once it terminates, other than drawing another arrow to the GUI process.

Is there a better way of presenting a process looping back to its parent on return/exit other than drawing another arrow back to the parent?

Comment: I added an answer, hoping that you really mean a flowchart, and not something else like a UML sequence diagram.

Comment: You would be correct. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ordinary [flowchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) (not a UML diagram), any box that represents some other process, subroutine or method (returning back to the caller) would be represented by a box having double-vertical lines instead of single, the ***Predefined Process Symbol.***

[image]

Return to the calling entity is indicated by flow control passing through the box, and out the other side, just as it would with any other non-terminating shape.

Comment: +1 May I ask where the image is from?

Comment: http://www.v7n.com/forums/attachments/graphic-design-forum/5655d1182140381-3d-flowchart-shapes-flowchart.png